# Hide element after 1 sec

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to hide an element and then reappear after 1 sec.

```
var obj = document.getElementById("myId");

obj.onclick = function() {
   this.style.display = "none"

   setTimeOut(function() {
      obj.style.display = "block";
   }, 1000);
}
```

I am able to hide it, but its not reappearing, what is the issue here?

Comment: `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut`

Comment: I'm pretty sure your browser console would've had something to say about `setTimeOut`

Comment: JS doesn't compile, therefore you don't get a notification `setTimeOut` does not exist... additionally, browsers don't intrude the user of JS errors by default, so you should always look at the JS Console to see errors that occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTimeout takes delay as the second argument if you want to wait for specific time to execute and you forgot to pass the time argument (*before your edit of the question*).

```
 setTimeout(function() {
      obj.style.display = "block";
   }, 1000); //1000ms  = 1 sec
```

Also note that the small `o` in out.

Comment: FYI the delay argument is optional. The OP's issue was a typo in the spelling of the function

Comment: Did he edit the answer? That is exactly what he has in there right now.

Comment: @j08691 Thankyou. Adjust my wording a bit.

Comment: @Michal Yes Michal. An Edit made by OP after my answer.

Comment: @Chaitanya No problem. Glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `setTimeOut to setTimeout`  and pass a time in milliseconds to wait for delay optionally:

> The setTimeout() method
>
> delay Optional The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second),
>   the timer should wait before the specified function or code is
>   executed. If this parameter is omitted, a value of 0 is used, meaning
>   execute "immediately", or more accurately, as soon as possible. Note
>   that in either case, the actual delay may be longer than intended; see
>   Reasons for delays longer than specified below.

[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
   var obj = document.getElementById("myId");
    
    obj.onclick = function() {
       this.style.display = "none"
       
       setTimeout(function() {
          obj.style.display = "block";
       }, 1000);
    }
```

```html
<div id="myId">Test</div>
```